# webapi filter properties from dictionary<string,string>

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata

I return a `IQueriable<Dictionary<string,string>>` in my POST method. I want to be able to apply OData filter on the dictionary. For example:

dictionary is

```
Key = Place
Value = New York

my filter is ?$filter=Place eq 'New York'
```

**

> But I get an error: ":"Instance property 'Place' is not defined for
>   type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String

**

Comment: Please provide your code and sample data :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution with third party lib. LinqToQuerystring

var queryValue = Request.RequestUri.ParseQueryString();
return _dictionary.LinqToQuerystring(queryValue.ToString());

Answer (score 0):

I think you can solve your problem more simply by creating a GET method named 'Places' that takes a parameter named `key` and return the result of looking up the `key` value in the Dictionary instance of that controller. Something like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public string Places(string key) {
    //TODO: Handle validation of value key parameter & missing keys
    return _placesDictionary[key];
}
```

The `IQueryable` implementation is intended to work against strongly typed collections. You're pseudo code shows you intend to query a dictionary by key value.

`IQueryable<Dictionary<string,string>>` actually defines a ***collection*** of `Dictionary<string,string>` instances. The error you're seeing is absolutely correct, there in no property named `Place` in the `Dictionary` type.